# Mach-O How To Determine Procedure Names

Tags: mach-o

I am currently learning about Mach-O Binary files and I am stuck trying to figure out how to determine which method names link to which procedure.

I am using Hopper to understand mach-o binaries and It knows how to link the method names with their target procedures. I am not completely sure but I have a feeling this is could be stated in one of the load commands, maybe `_unwind_info`? But I think it is simply placed in order in the `__LINKEDIT` section.

I simply want to know how `_main` in `__LINKEDIT` is linked to its correct  procedure in `__text` section

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at the `LC_SYMTAB` load command.

Comment: Ok Thanks I will look into it